# grep, sed or awk to compare content of two files

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, line

I have the following issue that I'm trying to solve in bash. I have two different files (file1, file2) contaning a list of information like the following:

```
HWI-1KL104:145:C18ANACXX:5:1101:1168:2164   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GTGCCTGAACTGGATGCATNGACAATGGGGAACATTACATATATAATACAAGGGAAACTCAAACGTTTCCNNNNNCAAGTATTTGACAGNNNNNNNNNNNN   @B@DDFFFHHHHHIHIJIJ#3AFGHHJJJJIIJJIJIIIJJJJJJJGIIJIJJJIJIJJJJIJJI=@EED#####,,5=;ADDFEEDDD############
```

The string showed represent A SINGLE LINE. Meaning that if I do:

```
grep "HWI-1KL104:145:C18ANACXX:5:1101:1168:2164" file1
```

my output is the string above. The *HWI-1KL104:145:C18ANACXX:5:1101:1168:2164* represents the ID of my line

You have to imagine millions of lines like this (~8GB of txt file) with different IDs

What I have to do is:

1. search for those IDs present in file1 that are present in file2
2. save the matched lines in file2 into a new file containing ONLY the ID + following information:

> HWI-1KL104:145:C18ANACXX:5:1101:1196:2120
>   CCCCTTCTCCAGGGGACCANGTATGTTTCTCTTATGGTCCTCCTTGTTTACTAGCTTCTCTGGCAGTGAGATTGTAGGCTGGTAATCCTTTACTCNNTNNN CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJJJ#4CDEEDCDDDDDC######

so, discarding the stuff represented by 4 * 0 0 * * 0 0 (that is fixed in terms of lenght but not in content..meaning that could be 3 * 1 0 * * 0 1 and so on..).

So my file1 represent a sort of "reference" of my IDs that I want to find and save in file2.

It is quite difficult to me to explain. I hope you understand what I would like to do.

I think that a `grep` should work but I don't know how to `grep` just some information within a line and compare to another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a for loop

```
    outputfile="/tmp/something"
    file1=3; file2=4; 
    for ids in $(cat $file1|awk '{print $1}'); 
    do
          #echo working on $id**
          grep $ids $file2|awk '{print $3" "$4" "$5}' >> $outputfile
    done
```

Above is the same script now expanded and the output sent to a file, so rather than pumping script to a file - you could execute the script and let it handle where it puts the output.

Sure you can run it on large files, it may just take a while to get going and may take some time to finish, the problem with using this method is that it works and is easy use but may not be as fast as some of the other complex methods suggested.

You could enable the working on id line to get more verbosity

additional notes:

```
for filesfound in $(pattern=1101; grep $pattern 3*|awk -F":" '{print $1}'); do
 echo "found $filesfound"; 
 grep "newpattern" $filesfound; 
 done;

found 3
found 33
```

you could dig further into initial grep like this:

```
 grep $pattern *|awk -F":" '{print "-- FILE: " $1 " --- ENTIRE_STRING: "$0}'
-- FILE: 3 --- ENTIRE_STRING: 3:HWI-1KL104:145:C18ANACXX:5:1101:1168:2164   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GTGCCTGAACTGGATGCATNGACAATGGGGAACATTACATATATAATACAAGGGAAACTCAAACGTTTCCNNNNNCAAGTATTTGACAGNNNNNNNNNNNN   @B@DDFFFHHHHHIHIJIJ#3AFGHHJJJJIIJJIJIIIJJJJJJJGIIJIJJJIJIJJJJIJJI=@EED#####,,5=;ADDFEEDDD############
-- FILE: 33 --- ENTIRE_STRING: 33:HWI-1KL104:145:C18ANACXX:5:1101:1168:2164   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GTGCCTGAACTGGATGCATNGACAATGGGGAACATTACATATATAATACAAGGGAAACTCAAACGTTTCCNNNNNCAAGTATTTGACAGNNNNNNNNNNNN   @B@DDFFFHHHHHIHIJIJ#3AFGHHJJJJIIJJIJIIIJJJJJJJGIIJIJJJIJIJJJJIJJI=@EED#####,,5=;ADDFEEDDD############
```

This is now returning file name|all string then looking for pattern and returning everything after the pattern - you can customise it by adding more awk statements on the end of the line

```
pattern=1101; grep $pattern *|awk -F":" '{print $1"|"$0}'|awk -F"$pattern" '{print $2}'
:1168:2164   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GTGCCTGAACTGGATGCATNGACAATGGGGAACATTACATATATAATACAAGGGAAACTCAAACGTTTCCNNNNNCAAGTATTTGACAGNNNNNNNNNNNN   @B@DDFFFHHHHHIHIJIJ#3AFGHHJJJJIIJJIJIIIJJJJJJJGIIJIJJJIJIJJJJIJJI=@EED#####,,5=;ADDFEEDDD############
:1168:2164   4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GTGCCTGAACTGGATGCATNGACAATGGGGAACATTACATATATAATACAAGGGAAACTCAAACGTTTCCNNNNNCAAGTATTTGACAGNNNNNNNNNNNN   @B@DDFFFHHHHHIHIJIJ#3AFGHHJJJJIIJJIJIIIJJJJJJJGIIJIJJJIJIJJJJIJJI=@EED#####,,5=;ADDFEEDDD############
```

Comment: perfect! it works! Thank you very much!!! However I do not understand how to print it to a file I put > results.txt after '{print $3" "$4" "$5}' but it didn't work. I tried also ./test.sh | tee results.txt it worked but it printed out also the results!

Comment: solved...sorry it was just: ./myscript.sh > results.txt shame on me :) Just a question...do you think it will works in a reasonable time with a file2 of 25GB? File1 us just 5Mb.

Comment: no problems, I have modified original post and given more insight to your questions.

Comment: my idea instead going through more complicated method is to split the big file in smaller files and do a grep to them. Do you think it could speed up the analysis? However it is possible to do a grep to multiple files? I've tried: do grep $ids file*| awk... but it doesn't work...

Comment: pattern=1101; grep $pattern 3*|awk -F":" '{print $1}'
yep the above will print out each file that contains your pattern where filename is 3 or 33 or anything if you changed 3* to just * then its all files..

Comment: It doesn't work very quicly...I need something faster (it takes 30 hours to produce 180Kb!). I will open a new thread that maybe can help also other user. In any case, thank you because it is a really nice starting point!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23639/discussion-between-vahid-and-fabioln79)

Answer (score 2):

Assuuming file2 contians just a list of the key ids you want:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ids[$0];next} $1 in ids{print $1,$10,$11}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which fields of file2 you want, but a good starting point would be something like this:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,9,10
```

Or if file2 is tab delimited:

```
grep -Ff file1 file2 | cut -f1,9,10
```

On a side note, you should probably be keeping this data in database and not a text file.

Comment: I think file2 is tab delimited. What 9 and 10 representing?

Answer (score 0):

Is `4 * 0 0 * * 0 0` always in the same format? It's a little tough to say how to answer this without knowing the various possible cases. What about the id, is that always in the same format?

To get just the id by using grep (and not the entire line) use `-o`. That returns just the matched text, and not the entire line.

For writing to the new file and discarding the `4 * 0 0 * * 0 0` you could use `grep -v` to grep the inverse of a string. So if you already know what line you're working with, `grep -v '4 * 0 0 * * 0 0'`

Anyway, a lot of this is going to depend on the exact format of your input as well as various edge cases, but that might get you started.

Comment: yes 4 * 0 0 * * 0 0 are always in the same format, however they change in content. The ID also is in the same format

Comment: Gotcha, then it should be fairly easy to use some regular expressions to snag what you're looking for with grep.